# How to increase by 1 withing (private static function)

Tags: function, html, numbers

I'm working on a new website with an API of Bol.com and I'm stuck at the moment.
My question is really simple, but i cant solve this issue. I just want to have a number for every div which needs to increase by 1.

This code will result an book within a div:

```
private static function printIndex($product) {

echo '<div id="indexboxes">';    
echo '<div id="itemleft"><img src=" ' . $product->getImagemedium() . ' " width="135" height="210"></div>';  
echo '<div id="itemmiddle">'; 
echo '<div id="itemmiddlename"><h2>' . $product->getTitle() . "</h2></div>"; 
echo '<div id="itemmiddlepub"><h3> ' . $product->getPublisher() . "</h3></div>";
echo '</div></div>';
}
```

It needs to be like this:

Number 1
Image 
Title
Publisher

Number 2
Image 
Title
Publisher

Number 3
Image 
Title
Publisher

etc..

The image, title and the publisher is working already.. But the numbers doesnt work.
How can get the numbers in this div?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something better than `<h2>`. Why not use an ordered list `<ol>` element and list items `<li>` instead.  You can use CSS counters and `li:before` to get the "Number ?" before each item.

Why not use HTML and CSS capabilities when they are the most natural way of doing the job? In any case, using this print method and putting ids on your divs will cause ids to be used more than once on the same page. You do not want to do that; ids must be unique.

I suggest you do a static mockup of what you want your page to look like; don't use PHP, use lists for styling, and use CSS to format the text sizes and the 'Number' prefix you want. Then, add the PHP to get the dynamism you want.

Comment: It is working now! Thank you very much! I have never heard of numbering with CSS.. Thank you!!!

Comment: You probably want the title and publisher to be `<span>`s, not `<div>`s.  Divisions are block elements by default, like paragraphs, frame sets, and the new HTML 5 header and footer elements.  Spans are inline by default, which is what you want.  In fact, look at some of the good HTML tutorial sites. And, think about how people would write static web pages with lists, images, and menus without PHP. Other people have solved the same problems you face; learn from them.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the index into your function by reference: eg:

```
private static function printIndex($product, &$idx) {

// your code

$idx++;

}
```